# Add Comment to Sales Report

Tags: onepage-checkout, reports, order-grid

I have a custom report based on the tutorial at http://wrightcreativelabs.com/create-a-custom-magento-report-product-skus-in-new-orders/.  The report is working well as is.  Now I'm trying to add a customer comments column to the report.  The customer comments are coming from the One Page Checkout extension.  I have the column added with:

```
    $this->addColumn('comment', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('reportneworders')->__('Special Instructions'),
        'align' => 'left',
        'sortable' => false,
        'index' => 'comment'
    ));
```

The problem is in the collection.  The gift message works, but when the comment is added, the report is broken.  I know I must be using the wrong id or reference to the comment.

```
    ->joinLeft(
            array('c' => 'order_comment'),
                  'c.order_comment = order_items.order_comment',
                  array(
                          'comment' => 'comment'
                  ))

    ->joinLeft(
            array('g' => 'gift_message'),
                  'g.gift_message_id = order_items.gift_message_id',
                  array(
                          'message' => 'message'
                  ))
```

The One Page Checkout textarea for the comment looks like this:

```
<textarea name="order-comment" id="order-comment"><?php echo trim(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getOrderCustomerComment()) ?></textarea>
```

I appreciate any advice.

Comment: "The gift message works, but when the comment is added, the report is broken." what do you mean by broken?

Comment: Maybe thats a little unclear.  I mean, without the 'order_comment' joinLeft statement, the report works fine.  When the joinLeft for 'order_comment' is added, the report doesn't load.

Comment: Do you get any error messages or logs?

Comment: I'm getting "
There has been an error processing your request."  In the log its not clear where the error is. But I'm sure its related to a DB error resulting from trying to fetch the order comment improperly.

Comment: Have a look at http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/429/158 maybe you can get a more complete error message

Comment: @Mike, were you able to solve this issue? If so, how?